# Result of executable

Tags: matlab, exe

Is there any method to pass the output of an executable apart from displaying in the console or writing the output in a text file? The executable is a MATLAB file.

Comment: In what environment are you running the executable? MATLAB, Windows command prompt, linux...?

Comment: Windows. I am calling the executable from php.

Answer (score 1):

In linux/unix, redirect your output to /dev/null, it will discard it.
In Windows, redirect to NUL.